# C++ using object of a class declared after

Tags: c++

for some reason i have to declare multiple classes in the same file, and in paricoular I have to use an object of one of these classes before declaring, here is an example:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class square{

    double side;
    double area;
    square(double s){
        side = s;
    }

    void calcArea(){
        area = side*side;
    }

    void example(){
        triangle t(2.3,4.5);
        t.calcArea();
    }

};

class triangle{

    double base;
    double height;
    double area;

    triangle(double s,double h){
        base = s;
        height = h;
    }

    void calcArea(){
        area = (base*height)/2;
    }
};

int main(){ 
}
```

You can see that in example() method in square class, I use an object belonging to class triangle that is declared after its use.
There's a way in order to let work this pieces of code?

Comment: Please indent your code correctly before seeking any help.

Comment: I don't see why this is downvoted; whilst it's quite basic it's a well formed question. However, it's likely answered somewhere else and therefore a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

Since `square` needs `triangle`, but `triangle` doesn't need `square`, you can simply change the order of the class definitions:

```
class triangle {
    // ...
};

class square {
    // ...
};
```

Or, since `example` is the only thing in `square` that needs `triangle`, define `example` after the definition of `triangle`:

```
class square {
    // ...
    void example();
};

class triangle {
    // ...
};

void square::example() {
    triangle t(2.3,4.5);
    t.calcArea();
}
```

Comment: You could also forward declare the necessary class before defining it.

Comment: Forward-declarations don't help here: `triangle t(2.3,4.5);`